# How to receive blob in Laravel API from the front end

Tags: laravel, jspdf

I am sending blob PDF generated by JSPDF to Laravel API from the front end, but Laravel doesn't seeing it and saying the the field is required, when I console.log() the blob I see that it exists as bellow

```
Blob
    size: 2888211
    type: "application/pdf"
    [[Prototype]]: Blob
```

the code in Laravel to store it

```
$report = $request->file('report');
$ext = $report->getClientOriginalExtension();
$report_name = $request->qr_url . ".$ext";
$report->move(public_path('uploads/reports/'), $report_name);
```

What is the wrong here please?

Comment: How are you sending it? Likely needs to be a POST using FormData for the request to see it on the Laravel side.

Answer (score 0):

Why ?

just send them as files

```
let reader = new FileReader();
reader.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
    // send that file
    let file = event.target.result;
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', file);
    let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("POST", "endpoint url");
    request.send(formData);
});
reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
```